# TCP packet really strange things happening

Tags: c++, tcp, packet

I'm writing a small command line tool to interact with a client (a game, nothing illegal though, just experimenting), mainly over HTTP.
I have written an older version of this tool some time ago and run into some problems which I now have fixed.

That's why I wanted to rewrite my code to have it more clear and just nicer. But now I run into some really wired problems and cant find out why.

I do all of this on a Mac with XCode. The problem occurs while I send the server's (I'm the server) version (plaintext HTML). The strange thing is, I copy/pasted that part of the code from my old version, and there it is working even when I run it now.
So I have two programs with exact the same code, but only one of them is working correctly.

This is the procedure:

1. Open up a socket and bind to a specific port, wait for client.
2. If client asks for server version, respond with plain HTML + version number
3. Done.

2 programs, same code, different results:

old version: client reads out version number correctly
new version: client fails to read out version number

This is the code to write the data over the socket (keep in mind this is the old ugly code fro the old version):

```
int socketWriteNormal_Old(int socket, std::string data, int mode, char final_buffer[], int bytes){
    if(mode == 0){
        char buffer[512];
        int error;
        std::string chunk;

        if(data.length() > 511){
            while(data.length() > 0){
                if(data.length() >= 511){
                    chunk = data.substr(0,511);
                    data = data.substr(511, data.length());
                }
                else{
                    chunk = data;
                    data = "";
                }
                bzero(buffer, 512);
                chunk.copy(buffer, chunk.length());
                error = write(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                if(error < 0){
                    return error;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            bzero(buffer,512);
            data.copy(buffer,512);
            error = write(socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        }

        return error;
    }
    else{
        int error = write(socket, final_buffer, bytes);

        std::cout << final_buffer << " " << bytes << std::endl;
        std::cout << error << std::endl;

        return error;
    }
}
```

This is how I listen on a port (connection seems to work on both versions):

```
int socketListen(int socket, int port){

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    int newsock;

    socklen_t clilen;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    std::cout << "[socketListen] Binding server_socket to port " << port << std::endl;

    if(bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "[socketListen] Running Listen()" << std::endl;

    listen(socket,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    std::cout << "[socketListen] running accept()" << std::endl;
    newsock = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    std::cout << "[socketListen] got new socket!" << std::endl;
    if(newsock < 0){
        return -2;
    }
    else{
        return newsock;
    }
}
```

This is the packet dump of whireshark of both packets created with the new and with the old version.

old and working version:

[image]

new and not working version:

[image]

As you can see, there is no difference.. or at least I can not find one. This is really driven me crazy, never had such strange problems..

Also, with the new version, I got another problem. The tool has a second function which downloads specific data from a server, also plain HTTP and binary data. The strange thing is, when I run the programm from command line I get a segfault after 3-6 seconds, but when I run it over XCode/gdb it does work fine...

If anyone had same strange problems or does know something about this, pls help me.

Comment: There is no langauge C/C++! This is no C code.

Comment: First thing you should fix, is your code it's a mess. And this is ceratinly not [tag:c].

Comment: What does this question have to do with the Paradox database system?

Comment: Okay, its C++. I know that. Is it really worth commenting that on here and not telling any usefull information? Also, i know that the code is a mess, thats why i wanted to rewrite it (as mentioned), but (as mentioned) only my old code seems to work/the old programm seems to work. I mean, both versions use the same code, but only the old version works. Also, this has nothing to do with the Paradox database system (why your thinking that?), i just find my problem paradox...

Comment: Why did you post the old version of the code, which you say was working, instead of the new version that you're having trouble with? And you haven't actually said what the problem is with the new version.

Comment: Put your mouse over the "paradox" tag and see what it says.

Comment: Enable core dumps on your Mac, so you can debug the core file and see where the segfault occurred.

Comment: Why are you writing the data in chunks? Why not just `write(socket, data.c_str(), data.size());` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by old and new versions, since you also say you didn't change anything. So they're the same version. Do you mean you just recompiled the code, and after doing that it no longer works the same as before?

Comment: The new version and the old version of the code produce the same result in the new version of my tool. Kinda hard to explain. Im using the old code so that there should be no difference between the working version and the non working, but even tho they have the same code, they produce different results. How can that be?

Comment: I'm still not getting it. What is the difference between the old version and the new version?

Comment: Idk why i wrote that in chunks.. But it worked. Old version = first attempt to write this tool some month ago, new version = todays attampt to rewrite it. I ran into a problem with the function i mentioned above so i tryed out my compiled old version i found somewhere on my hd => worked. So i copyed the code from the old version into the new one => did not work even tho they are same and produce the same tcp/ip packet.

Comment: Probably the receiving code has one of the typical TCP bugs such as not observing the size of data actually read. Post the receiving code

Comment: Unanswerable without the receiving code. But ... It's irrelevant why two pieces of poor code don't produce the same results. What you should be asking is the best way to produce the desired result.

Comment: The problem is: i dont have the receiving code. Its a game and i can only read the command line debug output of it.